# Handling JavaScript errors with window.onerror

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to handle my errors, but unfortunately I don't succeed.

In my AngularJS App 'run' I write this code:

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line, col, error) {
    alert('error');
};
$timeout(() => errorrr);
```

And while I do see an error on console:

> ReferenceError: errorrr is not defined

I do not get an alert...

---

If I execute the same code, outside of the App's 'run', it works.

Why/How can I fix it?

---

**Edit**
Using angular, I can't get to the $rootScope

```
angular.module('app').factory('$exceptionHandler', function ($log, $rootScope) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
        $log.error(exception, cause);
        $rootScope.errors.push({
            exception: exception,
            cause: cause
        });
    };
});
```

It throws

> Circular dependency found: $rootScope <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope

Is there a way to get $rootscope within this factory?

Comment: AngularJs has its own error handling routine. See [the documentation for `$exceptionHandler`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Edited, used $exceptionHandler, but I can't call $rootscope from it. Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking a different question... I was just noting why `window.onerror` was not picking up the error you were generating. If you have a new question, first search the internet and Stack Overflow for answers, then, if you don't find anything, ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in a comment to the question, using angular's own `$exceptionHandler` is preferable.

To fix the problem with circular injection, I needed to use the `$injector` service, like so:

```
angular.module('app').factory('$exceptionHandler', function ($log, $injector) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
        $log.error(exception, cause);
        var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $rootScope.errors.push({
            string: exception.toString(),
            message: exception.message,
            lineNumber: exception.lineNumber,
            stack: exception.stack,
            cause: cause
        });
    };
});
```